# How to set lunar calendar UIDatePicker in iOS

Tags: ios, calendar, uidatepicker

I need switch `UIDatePicker` between *Solar calendar* and *Lunar calendar*. With *Lunar calendar*, I can get *02/30/2016 (MM/dd/yyyy)*, but with *Solar calendar*, its never get *02/30/2016 (MM/dd/yyyy)*. So, how can set it in `UIDatePicker` ?

Comment: Are you sure that there is only one lunar calendar? I know several different lunar calendars (and several solar calendars, too). What kind of concrete calendar do you really speak about?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, all supported calendars can be found in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1652687-calendar_identifiers)

Comment: And this list in apple documentation contains at least 4 lunar calendars (all are variants of Islamic calendar).

Answer (score 0):

Lunar Calendar is also known is Chinese Calendar.  Try these

```
self.datePicker.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "zh")
self.datePicker.calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .chinese)
```

However, I tried both in simulator and with some app, there is no 2016/02/30 in Lunar.  There is 2016/2/29 which convert to 2016/4/6 in Solar.  There is 2015/02/30 Lunar (see below)

[image: Lunar Date Picker]

However, in the date picker, it shows all the leap months even it is invalid.